# How to delete files after pdf window close: Rails 3, wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

community!
I have my Rails 3 app with a task to delete .png files, that are included in the .pdf file, after the rendered pdf window close.
The pdf render code goes like this:
`<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag("/public/#{@current_user.username}/picture1.png") %>`,
 and the last line is 
`<% FileUtils.rm_r Dir.glob("./public/#{@current_user.username}/*") %>`
With such conditions my picture is not being rendered.
I need the second command to be triggered **after** the pdf window close.
Maybe You have some other solution to solve this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the files where they are. Have a background process that removes the files after they are N hours old. Could be an hour, or a day. Whatever makes sense for your app.